# xhr poll error ,socket.io not emitting messages or responding in local machine

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket, socket.io

edit: i added a connect_error listener to nodejs server, and it says its due to xhr poll error
so i have a nodejs file that emits a simple message to a web page and then displays it
when i click send in the web page it reloads and does nothing any clues on whats going on?
here is my js file

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
  });
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

this here is my html file
here you can see in the submit even i do execute the `preventDefault` function yet it reloads the page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      body { margin: 0; padding-bottom: 3rem; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }

      #form { background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15); padding: 0.25rem; position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; display: flex; height: 3rem; box-sizing: border-box; backdrop-filter: blur(10px); }
      #input { border: none; padding: 0 1rem; flex-grow: 1; border-radius: 2rem; margin: 0.25rem; }
      #input:focus { outline: none; }
      #form > button { background: #333; border: none; padding: 0 1rem; margin: 0.25rem; border-radius: 3px; outline: none; color: #fff; }

      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages > li { padding: 0.5rem 1rem; }
      #messages > li:nth-child(odd) { background: #efefef; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form id="form" action="">
      <input id="input" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
    
      var messages = document.getElementById('messages');
      var form = document.getElementById('form');
      var input = document.getElementById('input');
    
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (input.value) {
          socket.emit('chat message', input.value);
          input.value = '';
        }
      });
    
      socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
        var item = document.createElement('li');
        item.textContent = msg;
        messages.appendChild(item);
        window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
my file structure, in case if this is causing the problem
>root
 >node_modules
 >server/index.js
 >web/index.html
 >package-lock.json
 >package.json
```

Answer (score 0):

so the thing was that i wasnt viewing like it should for example
when i passed the default endpoint for express i should send a html file which was embedded for this
nothing else wrong with this though!